# LGSideMenuController: Registration of several local push notifications leads to delay in screen handling

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I noticed a strange issue when I registered several local push notifications:

```
for model in myModelArray
{
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let scheduleDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: i * 5, to: Date())!

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = scheduleDate
    notification.alertBody = "My push notification title"

    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    i += 1
}
```

When my local push notifications appear in background mode, I tap on it and want to present one screen directly:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification)
{
    let mainMenuVC = self.window?.rootViewController as! MenuViewController
    let navController = mainMenuVC.sideMenuController?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

    let myDestinationVC = navController.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyIdentifier") as! MyDestinationViewController
    navController.pushViewController(mydestinationVC, animated: false)
}
```

But it takes up to one minute for the transition between my menuVC and my destinationVC to happen. When my app is opened, pushing the view controller works perfectly. Did I forget about something? What is wrong with my code? The delay only happens when the app is closed and reopens again after tapping on the push notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UILocalNotification is deprecated since iOS10. You might receive your push notification, but func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) will never be called. The „delay“ you are experiencing is just the second local push notification, whose handling will work when your app is active.

Use UNUserNotificationCenter instead, but keep your „old handling“ for iOS9 devices.

Setup your notification like this:

```
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = „MyTitle“
        content.body = „MyBody“
        content.categoryIdentifier = UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier

        let units: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.second, .hour, .minute, .day, .month, .year]
        let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(units, from: date)

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)
```

and handle your received notification like that:

```
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
 {
    // Local Push notifications
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
    {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

        }
    }
    else
    {
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil))
    }

    return true
 }

 @available(iOS 10.0, *)
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
 {
    // handle your response here
    completionHandler()
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Why does no compiler warning indicate this deprecation? What a nasty bug. The only case the delegate method is not firing is when the app has been terminated. I will adjust the notification handling for iOS10.